# Trouble with the scanner -- Xsane

Tags: ubuntu, printer, scanner

I have Xsane on Ubuntu 12.04, with the scanner/printe/fax SAMSUNG_SCX_4729_FW. When trying to scan an image, with preview window open, and clicking the button "Acquire preview", I get an error message "failed to start scanner: Scanner cover is open". Of course, the cover is OK; I tried to switch my comp off, the printer off, etc., the same result. I also tried to scan without the use of preview window, but the problem persisted. A regular printing using  the same Samsung machine still works perfectly.   Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Scanner cover was indeed "open". Unfortunately, the error message was not too specific: the guilty party was one of two hinges at the back of the cover (to be precise, a lower side of the hinge that is supposed to plunge into the body of the scanner) -- the one which was  near the ***left side*** of the scanner. That part was not fully inserted -- just slightly off... Once I applied some force to it, it went down to a complete stop, and the status light changed from red to green. To bring the scanner to its normal operation mode, I had to turn it off and then turn it back on.